# How to keep the position of the caret in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

How can I keep the position of caret in contenteditable element, when I try to update the `innerHTML` of the editable element the caret position jumps to the first of the line, I need a function that can keep the position of the caret when editable element `innerHTML` is updated or changed thanks.

My code:

```
// content editable element
let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

editor.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        let lines = editor.children;
        for (let line of lines) {
            line.innerHTML += "Hello World !!!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer :

```
// content editable element
let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

// on keypress
editor.onkeypress = () => {
    // get the position of caret
    let pos = getCaretPos(editor.children[0]);

    // update the innerHTML
    editor.children[0].innerHTML += "Hello World !!!";

    // set the caret position
    setCaretPos(editor.children[0], pos);
}

function getCaretPos(element) {
    var ie = (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") && true;
    var w3 = (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") && true;
    var caretOffset = 0;
    if (w3) {
        var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
        preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
        caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
    } else if (ie) {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}

function setCaretPos(element, position) {
    var node = element;
    node.focus();
    var textNode = node.firstChild;
    var caret = position; // insert caret after the 10th character say
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, caret);
    range.setEnd(textNode, caret);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to not use `innerHTML`. If you're using contenteditable, the whole point of it is that you have a consistent active DOM document to work on. If you insert a string, the browser has no way of knowing where the cursor should be afterward because you are destroying all of the information it has. It is pretty much like you did `line.innerHTML = ""; line.innerHTML = "Hello World !!!";`, so the cursor gets pushed all the way to the beginning/end.

Given that, you can do

```
if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    // 1. Get the children as a normal JS array, so that adding
    //    children in the next bit of code doesn't break for for-of.
    let lines = Array.from(editor.children);
    // Old Browsers:
    //   let lines = Array.prototype.slice.call(editor.children);

    for (let line of lines) {
        const newText = "Hello World !!!";

        // 2. Insert the text immediately after the 'line' DOM node.
        line.after(newText); 
        // Older Browsers:
        //   line.parentNode.insertBefore(
        //     document.createTextNode(newText), line.nextSibling);

    }
    // 3. Normalize the document, so that if the code above inserted multiple text nodes
    //    in a row (potentially meaning that `editor.children` is no longer just lines), 
    //    the nodes will be merged back together.
    editor.normalize();
}
```

Without knowing what `editor.children` actually specifically contains, I can't be 100% certain that this will work, but something like it certainly should.